# Center Graphics elements relative to one another, rather than to the full figure

Tags: labeling, graphics

Suppose I wish to generate the following figure in Mathematica:

[image: Plot of sinusoidal function with labeled arrow indicating one period of oscillation]

My thought was to build it in parts. First, I make the plot:

```
p = Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image: Plot of Sin[2 Pi x]]

Then I make the annotation:

```
g = Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Arrow[{{1/4, 1.2}, {5/4, 1.2}}], 
    Style[Text[" Period ", Center], Background -> White]
}]
```

> [image: Double-headed arrow labeled "Period"]

But when I combine them, Mathematica interprets the `Center` specification I gave to `Text` to mean the center *of the entire figure*, rather than the center *of the `Arrow`*. So I get the unfortunate output

```
Show[p, g, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: My incorrect attempt to combine the plot with the arrow]

How do I tell Mathematica I want the `Text`'s position to be centered relative to the `Arrow`, not relative to the entire figure?

(I have a lot of things like this to do, so I prefer not to have to specify coordinates for the `Text` explicitly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we create the plot:

```
p = Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}];
```

Next we create the arrow, in its own system of coordinates. We will find it convenient to choose coordinates such that the arrow begins at the origin and is of unit size:

```
g = Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[{-0.1, 0.1}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
    Style[Text[" Period ", Center], Background -> White]
}];
```

Finally we'll use the four-argument form of the [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) function (`Inset[obj, pos, opos, size]`) to insert the arrow into the plot. To use, we must specify the object `obj` we wish to inset, two points — `pos` in the main plot's system of coordinates and `opos` in the arrow's system of coordinates — which should coincide in the final graphic, and a `size` parameter to set the relative scale of the two objects.

We'll choose `pos` to be `{1/4, 1.2}`, the position where we want the arrow to begin, which means we should choose `opos` to be `{0, 0}`. And since we made our arrow unit-sized, the `size` parameter should just be the total desired width of the arrow in the plot's coordinate system, here `5/4 - 1/4`. Putting it all together,

```
Show[p, PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 0.3}}, 
    Epilog -> Inset[g, {1/4, 1.2}, {0, 0}, 5/4 - 1/4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use inset. Then only the center needs specification. Even Arrow can be defined in its own coordinate system.

```
Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.1, 0.1}], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
     Style[Text[" Period ", Center], Background -> White]}], {.75, 
    1.2}], PlotRange -> 1.3]
```

[image]

Comment: `Inset` looks like probably a good approach. But I do still want to use my knowledge of the endpoints, rather than computing what the center ought to be. Also you have included no provision to be sure the scale of the annotation is correct relative to the scale of the graph.

Comment: I can address both of these concerns by using more arguments in `Inset`, namely:  `Epilog -> Inset[Graphics[…], {1/4, 1.2}, {0, 1}, 5/4 - 1/4]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom `Arrowheads` directive using the label as an arrow head:

```
arrowheads[lbl_] := Arrowheads[{{-0.04, 0}, {0.04, 1}, 
    {.1, .5, Graphics @ Text @ Framed[lbl, FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White]}}];

Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {arrowheads["Period"], Arrow[{{0.25, 1.1}, {1.25, 1.1}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1.3]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {arrowheads["Period"], Arrow[{{0.25, 1.1}, {1.25, 1.1}}], 
   Red, arrowheads[Style["another label", Green, 16], 
   Arrow[{{.25, -.75}, {2.7, .5}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1.3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> 1.5];
g = Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], 
    Arrow[{{1/4, 1.2}, {5/4, 1.2}}], 
    Style[Text[" Period ", Mean@{{1/4, 1.2}, {5/4, 1.2}}], 
     Background -> White]}];
```

[image]

Comment: True, that works in the simple case, but I'd still prefer a more general solution for centering items relative to other items without having to specify coordinates explicitly. (For instance, on `LogPlot`s and `LogLogPlot`s, the midpoint of two coordinates is more complicated than just their arithmetic mean.)

Comment: @thecommexokid Center places the Text at the center of the image not the center of the plot object. check this `Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Arrow[{{1/4, 1.2}, {5/4, 1.2}}], 
  Style[Text[" Period ", Center], Background -> White]}, Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}]` you need to manipulate used coordinate to specify the position of the text

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `Epilog` and `Inset`. One must take care about the coordinates of the arrow, the text, and the inset box.

```
Plot[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 3},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, .2}},
  Epilog -> 
    Inset[Graphics[{
      Arrowheads[{-0.07, 0.07}],
      Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
      Text[Style[" Period ", Background -> White], {.5, 0}]}],
    {.75, 1.05}]]
```

[image: plot]

Note that the end points of the arrow are placed at x = 0 and x = 1 and the text is centered at x = .5, the mid-point of arrow. These coordinates are local to the inset box. Then the inset box is centered at plot coordinates x = .75 and y = 1.05 to position the annotation properly in plot.

Comment: This answer still requires me to compute where I want the center of the inset box to go, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid in the original question. Using the various answers I've received here, I've posted my own Answer that uses the 4-argument form of `Inset` to avoid this.